# Error when changing UITableView.Frame

Tags: ios, ios4

I have a `UITableView` that is set when the screen is originally loaded and sits at `(0,44)`.  After an action is performed the table is reloaded and the frame needs to be adjusted to full screen `(0,0)`.

When I run

```
self.table.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.table.frame.size.width, self.table.frame.size.height + 44);
```

I get this error:
`'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 4 beyond bounds for empty array'`

I also noticed if I hardcode a height value fo `358` or lower the code will run, but if its `359` or higher I get the same error.

Comment: Is there any code around there that deals with arrays?

Comment: Add this just above your self.table.frame: NSLog(@"OLD FRAME %@", NSStringFromCGRect(self.table.frame) ); Then add a new CGRect frame; variable and set your CGRectMake to that variable, then log that before you go set the frame. If it still fails then add this at the top NSLog@"CLASS %@", NSStringFromClass([self.table class]) );

Comment: @DavidH Thanks! When I inserted that code it showed me where it was bombing in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. When you reset the frame `cellForRowAtIndex` was getting fired before my NSMutableArray was getting populated!

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates you're going out of bounds of an array, so check every part of your UITableViewDataSource and UITableViewDelegate methods for where you're accessing arrays and see if any of them could cause problems.  Use breakpoints and NSLog() to see where the crash occurs.

If I were you, I'd start by looking at `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.  I'll be there's a line somewhere in there that is pulling an item from an array without first checking to see if the array has that many items.  When your table is in the smaller frame, it's showing fewer rows, so you're not going out of bounds (yet).  Then when you grow the frame, the table will try to show more rows than there are elements in the array, causing the crash.